# How to Pass Image in ImageList to PictureBox in Reverse Index Order

Tags: vb.net, picturebox, imagelist

I have a VB.Net application which has spelling words that a child can type in and it verifies the spelling. On the form, I have a **Next** and **Back** button, which advances a `PictureBox` with items contained in an `ImageList`. I have 3 items in the `ImageList` collection with an `index[2]`.

Here's the code that I'm using to advance the Next button to display the next image in the collection:

```
Private Sub btnNext_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnNext.Click
    'Get images and place them in the Imagebox on each click.

    Static count As Integer = 1

    If count > ImageList1.Images.Count - 1 Then
        count = 0
    End If
    PictureBox1.Image = ImageList1.Images(count)
    count += 1        

End Sub
```

While this works, I cannot figure out how to get this to work in the reverse order. Here's the `OnLoad` event handler that starts with the first image in the collection:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    'Set picturebox with initial picture

    PictureBox1.Image = ImageList1.Images(0)
    txtSpell.Focus()

End Sub
```

How can I get the **Back** button to go backwards in the index from it's current point in the index which is shown in the `PicutureBox` control? This is where I'm stumped. Tried to re-write the code several times, if I click **Next** once, I go to the next image `index[1]` and if click the **Back** button, it takes me to `index[0]`.

But if click next again, PictureBox jumps to `index[2]` the last image, rather than going back to `index[1]`. If I click **Back** again, the code is blowing up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, I would like to give thanks to both Ken White, and valter, for assisting me and opening up my thinking in this approach. I used Ken's advice on my variable naming and valter's approach for my first solution of the `btnNext` problem.

Thus, as I had a working `btnNext` to flip through my images in the `imagelist1` collection and push them to the `picturebox1`, I took Ken's advice arranged my code and renamed variables to get `btnPrevious` to work as such:

```
Private CounterVar As Integer = 0

Private Sub ImageUpdate()
    'Sets the picture box to the first image of the series.
    PictureBox1.Image = ImageList1.Images(CounterVar)

End Sub

Private Sub btnPrevious_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnPrevious.Click
    'Allow the Back button to respond the appropriate PictureBox item.
    If CounterVar = 1 Then   'This is the second imagelist item, index[1].
        CounterVar = 0       'This is the first imagelist item, index[0].
        ImageUpdate()

    ElseIf CounterVar = 2 Then   'This is the last imagelist item, index[2]. 
        CounterVar = 1           'This is the second imagelist item, index[1].
        ImageUpdate()

    Else
        CounterVar = CounterVar  'Otherwise, the count remains where it is till Back is clicked.
    End If
    ImageUpdate()

End Sub

Private Sub btnNext_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnNext.Click
    'Setup counter variable to begin the button processing.
    CounterVar += 1

    'Get Imagebox items and place them in the PictureBox, in order, on each click.
    If CounterVar > ImageList1.Images.Count - 1 Then
        CounterVar = 0
    End If
    ImageUpdate()

    'On a correct answer, clear the textbox, spell label, and hide the result label,
    'then set the focus of the textbox.

    txtSpell.Text = String.Empty
    lblAnsResult.Text = String.Empty
    lblAnsResult.Visible = False
    txtSpell.Focus()

End Sub

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    'Set imagebox to first index image.
    ImageUpdate()

    'Set focus to the textbox.
    txtSpell.Focus()

End Sub
```

This is what I was trying to accomplish with `btnPrevious`, without it skipping around or out of order. Although the code can skip around via Next, the user cannot go backward beyond the first image in the `Imagebox1` `index[0]`. This is what I wanted. Again, a BIG THANKS to those who helped me to think it out. That's what being on Stack is all about... learn from the answers you get, and run free developing in confidence... like a happy baby w/out a diaper!  Thanks fellas!

Answer (score 1):

Move your `count` variable (which is badly named, BTW - I've used `CurrIdx` instead) to a higher visibility. In the previous button's click handler, decrement the index; if it drops below 0, reset it to the `ImageList.Images.Count - 1` again. I'd also move the code that actually sets the image index to its own procedure, so that you're not repeating yourself and it's more clear. Something like this should work for you:

```
Private CurrIdx As Integer = 0

Private Sub UpdateImage()
    PictureBox1.Image = ImageList1.Images(CurrIdx)
End Sub

Private Sub PrevButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles PrevButton.Click
    CurrIdx -= 1
    If CurrIdx < 0 Then
        CurrIdx = ImageList1.Images.Count - 1
    End If
    UpdateImage()

End Sub

Private Sub NextButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles NextButton.Click
    CurrIdx += 1
    If CurrIdx > ImageList1.Images.Count - 1 Then
        CurrIdx = 0
    End If
    UpdateImage()
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    UpdateImage()
End Sub
```

Comment: Very nice. `CurrIdx` instead of `count`. You can have your 15 points!

Comment: Thanks, Ken. However your code causes a problem in going back in the application. The issue lies within the `btnPrevious` handler. I looked at it and looked at it... Then asked what's happening to count variable. You DID turn on the light switch for me, however, and I used your ideology to rearrange and make it work. If I post my solution, will I still be able to give you an up vote? I would like for you to see what I did. You and @valter have been instrumental in shaping my thinking during this, and I have no issues giving you guys the mention!

Comment: @DesignerMind: No, my code correctly handles going back in the `PrevButton_Click` handler, including wrapping from the beginning back around to the end. If you want it to stop at the beginnning instead of wrapping, just comment out that `if` statement. (I tested the code before posting to make sure it behaves properly.) And yes, you can still upvote mine if you'd like even though you've also posted an answer.

Comment: Gotcha Ken, I made sure that I isolated your code, to ensure that it did work, but for reason it kept misfiring. Weird.

I will isolate again tomorrow, and test it again. Either way, you've given me an approach to this and similar problems. I'll probably end up using it, but a C# version. Don't mistake that I'm not appreciative... I certainly am! ;)

Comment: I gave you a VB.Net version because you tagged your question that way. If you'd wanted C#, I could have provided that instead. :-)